# GWT 2.6.1 + SuperDevMode: stack traces are not deobfuscated on server

Tags: java, gwt, stack-trace, deobfuscation, gwt-super-dev-mode

Till May this year, I was using **GWT 2.5.1** and **simple DevMode** and was able to **send obfuscated** exceptions with stack traces **to server and deobfuscate them** there using **symbol maps** as per [this brilliant article](http://www.summa-tech.com/blog/2012/06/11/7-tips-for-exception-handling-in-gwt/). This helped me a lot.

Since June I successfully switched to **GWT 2.6.1** and **SuperDevMode** which provides quite decent experience comparing to **simple DevMode** and is simpler to use.

However, I noticed that my stack traces are not deobfuscated correctly on the server no more.
I keep getting obfuscated stack traces even after deobfuscation.

Following is the related contents of *.gwt.xml file:

```
<module rename-to="somemodule">

    <!-- inherits, stylesheet, entry-point, source elements are going here -->

    <add-linker name="xsiframe" />

    <extend-property name="locale" values="uk" />
    <set-property-fallback name="locale" value="uk" />

    <set-property name="compiler.stackMode" value="emulated" />
    <set-configuration-property name="compiler.emulatedStack.recordLineNumbers" value="true" />

    <set-property name="gwt.logging.logLevel" value="INFO" />            
    <set-property name="gwt.logging.enabled" value="TRUE" />  
    <set-property name="gwt.logging.developmentModeHandler" value="ENABLED" />    
    <set-property name="gwt.logging.systemHandler" value="DISABLED" />  
    <set-property name="gwt.logging.popupHandler" value="DISABLED" />  
    <set-property name="gwt.logging.consoleHandler" value="ENABLED" />   
    <set-property name="gwt.logging.firebugHandler" value="ENABLED" />
</module>
```

Following is server-side code that handles client side exceptions:

```
import static com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RpcRequestBuilder.STRONG_NAME_HEADER;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SerializableThrowable;
import com.google.gwt.logging.server.StackTraceDeobfuscator;

// ....

@Override
public void logClientException(final SerializableThrowable ex, final String userAgent, final String platform, final String moduleName) {
    final HttpServletRequest request = getThreadLocalRequest();

    final String symbolMapsDirectory = "webapps/" + getTomcatWebappFolder(request.getServletContext()) + "/WEB-INF/deploy/" + moduleName + "/symbolMaps";
    final String permutationName = request.getHeader(STRONG_NAME_HEADER);
    final Throwable original = new StackTraceDeobfuscator(symbolMapsDirectory).deobfuscateThrowable(ex.getThrowable(), permutationName);

    logClientException(original, userAgent, platform);
}
```

Did I omit something when transferred from **GWT 2.5.1** to **GWT 2.6.1**?

Thanks a lot in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an unfortunate known issue. See [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7693) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7460).

The problem is that with each recompile an entire new incremental directory tree gets created (see the compile-1, compile-2 etc subdirs). Hence the runnning application server (the one that hosts your servlets) will not be able to pick up the right `compile-x/extras/<module-name>/symbolMaps` directory to use with a call to setSymbolMapsDirectory (as @Vadim pointed out). And of course, is a quite a PITA to copy such `symbolMaps` in the expected directory each time you recompile (and I'm not even sure if it will work wrt permutation names).

This was the same for `GWT-RPC` at the beginning of the SuperDevMode era, but with the difference that the codeserver (SDM) now exposes all those *.gwt.rpc output files directly and if the `gwt.codeserver.port` java flag is used, your servlets will download policy files  automatically (only in localhost, and with GTW >= 2.5.1).

Anyway, the point is to let the codeserver expose/serve also the `symbolMaps` files (which is already somehow does, by hitting `http://localhost:9876/sourcemaps/<module-name>/gwtSourceMap.json` but only for sourcemaps and not in a `StackTraceCreator` comprehensible way) in some way, as descibed in the first issue.

Fortunately stacktraces are not *that bad* to live with on development.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Basically I came to same conclusion myself a day ago but didn't have a chance to write similar answer, hence accepting yours!

Yes, I agree that during development it's not a huge problem. Let's hope GWT team will solve this in the nearest future.

Answer (score 2):

Just yesterday I had a similar problem. With one exception - we use a build-in deobfuscation functionality in GWT logging. So my problem was in incorrect `symbolMapsDirectory` path. The bad news here is that GWT won't tell you if your symbolMaps path is incorrect:

`com.google.gwt.core.server.StackTraceDeobfuscator#loadSymbolMap:`

```java
try {
  BufferedReader bin = ...
} catch (IOException e) {
  // If the symbol map isn't found or there's an I/O error reading the file, the returned
  // mapping may contain some or all empty data (see below).
}
```

So our working solution looks like this:

```java
setSymbolMapsDirectory(getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/deploy/" + moduleName + "/symbolMaps/"));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But did you try to use this deobfuscator in `SuperDevMode` (not plain `DevMode` or production mode)? Because in `DevMode` or production mode everything works fine, the only problem is with `SuperDevMode`.

Comment: No, I didn't try. In SDM you works with symbolMap that is hosted by the localhost:9876. But GWT module sends request to /remote_logger to your real application server. If you don't put symbolMap from localhost:9876 to your real application server the /remote_logger will not be able to deobfustace stacktraces because of missing symbolMap. I think this is the problem.

Comment: Yes, you're right - I've also came to this conclusion. Let's wait till GWT team release a solution for this :)